# Existence of such formula that $\phi(p) \models p \leftrightarrow \psi$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let $\phi(p)$ be a formula which contains a variable $p$ and doesn't contain the variable $q$. Let $\phi(q)$ be a formula which is constructed in the following way: Every occurence of $p$ in $\phi(p)$ is replaced with $q$. 
Prove that if $$\phi(p), \phi(q) \models p \leftrightarrow q $$ then there exists a such formula $\psi$ ( which doesn't conatain $p$ and $q$ ) that $$\phi(p) \models p \leftrightarrow \psi$$

Please hint me because I cannot deal with it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try a structural induction on $\phi$? If so where is your problem?

Comment: @wece, thanks for your attention. I think about it. I try to do it but after I come back from the university. And I will write here if I encounter a problem.